# How to add field to upload image by Redux Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I want to make a submit form by Redux-Form which has a image upload field along with other text fields. I have tried the following approach for image upload and the problem is whenever I try to upload image the form gets re-rendered. How can I do it in a proper way? And another thing is How can I send entire form data (including uploaded image) to Back end? I have used here react,redux-form and material-ui

```
           <Box className={classes.controlTitle}>
              Upload Organization Logo
            </Box>
            <Field
              name="logo"
              type="file"
              component={renderField}
              placeholder="Upload your organization logo"
              className={classes.field}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using something like [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady). It takes care of the file upload for you and you can use any form/components/ui libraries with it:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback, useMemo, forwardRef } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import Uploady, {
  useBatchAddListener,
  useBatchFinishListener,
  useUploadyContext
} from "@rpldy/uploady";
import { asUploadButton } from "@rpldy/upload-button";

const MyUploadField = asUploadButton(
  forwardRef(({ onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("Select file");

    useBatchAddListener((batch) => {
      setText(batch.items[0].file.name);
      onChange(batch.items[0].file.name);
    });

    useBatchFinishListener(() => {
      setText("Select file");
      onChange(null);
    });

    return (
      <div {...props} ref={ref} id="form-upload-button" title={text}>
        {text}
      </div>
    );
  })
);

const MyForm = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(null);
  const uploadyContext = useUploadyContext();

  const onSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    uploadyContext.processPending({ params: fields });
  }, [fields, uploadyContext]);

  const onFieldChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setFields({
        ...fields,
        [e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value
      });
    },
    [fields, setFields]
  );

  const buttonExtraProps = useMemo(
    () => ({
      onChange: setFileName
    }),
    [setFileName]
  );

  return (
    <Form>
      <MyUploadField autoUpload={false} extraProps={buttonExtraProps} />
      <br />
      <input
        onChange={onFieldChange}
        id="field-name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="your name"
      />
      <br />
      <input
        onChange={onFieldChange}
        id="field-age"
        type="number"
        placeholder="your age"
      />
      <br />
      <button>
        id="form-submit"
        type="button"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        disabled={!fileName}
      >
        Submit Form
      </button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Uploady
        clearPendingOnAdd
        destination={{ url: "[upload-url]" }}
        multiple={false}
      >
        <MyForm />
      </Uploady>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-inside-form-ys1wx?file=/src/App.js) for a complete example.